# Issue setting vim colorscheme and auto-completion

Tags: vim

[image: Base16 faulty rendering]

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

I have installed Base16-Shell 256 color scheme. Downloaded whole Base16 Family of schemes, and followed every single step that they outlined.
https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim

My [.vimrc](https://ufile.io/aqhgw) and [.zshrc](https://ufile.io/yqetd) files:

This might point to something, when I enter su, it's kinda broken:

[image: SU has issues as well]

Comment: What have you tried? Which colorscheme is that? Does `:hi TabSpace ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE` work?

Comment: I found out that tab issue was due to my chosen theme...
Autocompletion is still an issue, didn't manage to solve it.

Comment: It's kinda obvious that I've switched to Vim yesterday, but I am already in love with it! 
And I am hoping that there will be some kind folks whom will smooth this transition to Vim for me. 

 ^_^

Comment: You switch to `$NEW_EDITOR` when you have reached the same level of proficiency in `$NEW_EDITOR` as in `$OLD_EDITOR`.

Comment: @romainl Well said :D But considering that stackO has an awesome community, I guess that someone will stumble upon this, and answer such a "noobish" question.

And, somehow, I feel that you find these sorta questions triggering.
Though, thanks that you've spared some time to help me B-)

Answer (score 0):

Holly cow, it's weird how powerful feelings Vim invokes!

For someone that might have similar "issue", here is the answer
:syntax on

[image: thadaa]

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a file as Root aka Super User(su) it will use the `.vimrc` of the root user. Because of this, you can copy your `~/.vimrc` to `/root/.vimrc` which is inside the home directory of the Root user.

I usually symlink instead of copying so that I will only need to make changes to my own `.vimrc` and root will be kept up to date.

Comment: I did symlink .zshrc, .vimrc and .oh-my-zsh , but it prevails, no matter what I do.
Though, this process of figuring "stuf" out is transitioning to an addiction to LinuxOS's ^_^ I don't even lose my nerves anymore, when I can't fix something that instance -- finally came to realize that patience has to be part of everyday linux usage.

Tnx for suggestion, anyway. Cheers.